# use-case streaming in pyspark

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, azure-databricks, spark-structured-streaming

I am working with Databricks on Azure, my data are hosted on ADLS2.
Current version of runtime is 10.4 LTS (I can upgrade if needed)

I have a table **Pimproduct**:

| id | name | action | dlk_last_modified | pim_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Article1 | A | 2022-03-01 | 2022-02-28 22:34:00 |

- id : the ID of the Article (unic)
- name : the Name of the Article
- Action : The action to execute on the line (A = add, D = delete)
- dlk_last_modified : the insert date in my table
- pim_timestamp : the extract date from the source system

Every ~15 min, I receive a new file which contains the modification I need to insert. For each line in my file, I consider only for each IDs the most recent `pim_timestamp`:

1. If the line is an action=A and the ID does not exist, I add the line
2. If the line is an action=A and the ID exists, I replace existing line for the same ID with the new line.
3. If the line is an action=D, I need to delete the ID from the table.

---

Initially, the modifications were daily. I was using this code:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W

df = spark.table("Pimproduct").unionByNames(
    spark.read.format("avro").load("/path/to/daily/data")
)

df = df.withColumn(
    "rn",
    F.row_number().over(W.partitionBy("id").orderBy(F.col("pim_timestamp").desc())),
)

df = df.where("rn = 1").where("action <> 'D'")

df.write.saveAsTable("pimproduct", format="delta", mode="overwrite")
```

But now, I want to do the same in streaming, and I do not really know how I could do that. I tried this:

```py
import tempfile
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W

df = spark.readSteam.table("Pimproduct").unionByNames(
    spark.readStream.schema(schema).format("avro").load("/path/to/daily/data")
)

df = df.withColumn(
    "rn",
    F.row_number().over(W.partitionBy("id").orderBy(F.col("pim_timestamp").desc())),
)

df = df.where("rn = 1").where("action <> 'D'")


with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as d:
    df.writeStream.toTable("Pimproduct", checkpointLocation=d)
```

but I got the error:

> AnalysisException: Non-time-based windows are not supported on streaming DataFrames/Datasets;

Any idea how I could perform this streamed data ingestion? I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: You need to use `foreachBatch` in combination with Delta Lake MERGE to update the data. Streaming Delta tables by definition are append only.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `foreachbatch` for updating the table with streaming data.

You can use below function to update your table.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
from delta.tables import *



def update_table2(df,id):
    source = DeltaTable.forName(spark,"Pimproduct")
    source.alias("src")\
    .merge(df.alias("upds"),"src.id == upds.id and upds.pim_timestamp > src.pim_timestamp")\
    .whenMatchedUpdateAll().execute()

    source = DeltaTable.forName(spark,"Pimproduct")
    source.alias("src").delete(condition="src.action=='D'")
```

And call the function like below.

`df.writeStream.foreachBatch(update_table2).start()`

Output:

[image]

Comment: this is very inefficient... you will rewrite all the data without need

Comment: @AlexOtt thanks for the comment, does partition on id could improve the performance while doing delta merge?
And could you provide your approach so that i can try at my end.

Comment: I meant first variant that overwrites the data

Comment: @AlexOtt solution updated